# RecyclerView select only one time at time

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I would like to implement function to select/unselect only one item at time - so "highlighted" is only one item.

I am using Android Annotation

**Holder**

```
@EViewGroup(R.layout.view_massage_item)
public class MassageTypeHolder extends LinearLayout {

    @ViewById
    Button item;

    @ColorRes(R.color.red) int textUnselected;
    @ColorRes(R.color.blue) int textSelected;


    public MassageTypeHolder(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MassageTypeHolder(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void bind(final Massage massage, OnRecyclerItemListener onRecyclerItemListener) {
        item.setText(massage.getName());
        item.setTextColor(textUnselected);
    }

    public void setChecked() {
        item.setBackgroundColor(textSelected);
    }

    public void setUnchecked() {
        item.setBackgroundColor(textUnselected);
    }

}
```

**Adapter**

```
@EBean
public class MassageTypeAdapter extends RecyclerViewAdapterBase<Massage, MassageTypeHolder> {

    private OnRecyclerItemListener onRecyclerItemListener;

    @RootContext
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected MassageTypeHolder onCreateItemView(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return MassageTypeHolder_.build(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewWrapper<MassageTypeHolder> holder, final int position) {
        final MassageTypeHolder typeHolder = holder.getView();
        final Massage massage = items.get(position);

        //TODO ON CLICK - select only one item

        typeHolder.bind(massage, onRecyclerItemListener);

    }

    public void setOnRecyclerItemListener(OnRecyclerItemListener onRecyclerItemListener) {
        this.onRecyclerItemListener = onRecyclerItemListener;
    }
}
```

I have tried many answers here, but nothing worked. Please help

Comment: what do you want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CarView Group with select an deselecting items in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200614/carview-group-with-select-an-deselecting-items-in-android)